# The generators of twisted homogeneous coordinate rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$.

Let $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $X$ and $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$.

Let $B := B(X, \sigma, \mathcal{L})$ the twisted coordinate ring in the sense of [Artin-Van Den Bergh](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186939090269T).

We assume that $\mathcal{L}$ is $\sigma$-ample.

It is well-known that $QCoh(X)$ is equivalent to the category the quotient category $Gr(B)/tor(B)$, where $Gr(B)$ is the category of left graded $B$-modules and $tor(B)$ is the full subcategory of $Gr(B)$ of torsion modules.

**Question**

In the above case,
is $B$ generated in degree 1 ?